# How do I eliminate this extra space that comes along with star pattern program?

Tags: c

```
// Correct me if I'm wrong, This code is kinda okay-ish but not giving me desired output  
// Here's the code: 
  #include<stdio.h>
  int main() {
      int i,j,num;
      printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
      scanf("%d",&num);
      for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
          for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
              if(j>=i){
                  printf("*");
              } else{
                  printf("\n");
              }
          }
  
      }
      return 0; }
```

```
Enter the number of rows: 5
***** 
**** 
 
*** 
 
 
** 
 
 
 
*
```

Please tell me why these extra spaces are there?

Comment: You're doing `printf("\n");` too often. Debug this yourself, it's most basic knowledge. A piece of paper and a pencil are most helpful here. Hint: you want `printf("\n");` once a complete line of `*` has been printed.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: I think the pattern you've shown looks nice enough. If you think it's the wrong pattern, please show the pattern you want to get.

Comment: ==> `printf("\n"); break;` to leave the inner loop soon.

Comment: Side note: your code is overly complicated, you don't need `if (j>=i)`  at all. Rethink it from scratch: you want to print N lines. The first line should contain 5 stars, the second one should contain 4 stars, the third one 3 stars etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that if() condition

When you write nested for() loops, for every "i" times outer loop iterates, inner one iterates "j" times,

So, look here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
 for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n";
 }
```

1.First goes for(i) i = 0, 0 is < 5, iterate code in for(i)

2.a) j = 0, 0 is < 5,

2.b) print: "*"  for every time j<5

2.c) j++, now j=1

This iterates 5 times for inner for(j), because j<5
And we get *****
3.Print a new line \n
4.i++, now i=1
5.Iterate code under 2.

This is a solution to your problem:

```
int main() {
    int i, j, num;
    printf("Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
   

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {

            printf("*");
            
        }
  
      printf("\n");

    }

    return 0;
}
```